# Postgresql trigger to update a column in a table when another table gets inserted or updated

Tags: sql, postgresql

Basically I have table_a and table_b. table_b is made with features from table_a and in common they share section_id column and status.

table_a's section_id is primary key so it's unique, but table_b can have multiple section_ids, but they all share same status

Users insert and update table_b and I want to capture the status changes back in table_a

```
CREATE TRIGGER table_b_aiu
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE
ON table_b
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (((new.status = 100) OR (new.status = 200)))
EXECUTE PROCEDURE table_b_aiu();

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION table_b_aiu()
RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
UPDATE table_a a
SET status = 100
FROM table_b b
WHERE (b.status = 100 or b.status = 200) 
AND a.section_id = b.section_id;
    RETURN new; 
END;
$BODY$
 LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
 COST 100;
```

The problem with this, is that instead of updating just the newly updated or inserted row, it updates the ENTIRE dataset, which is not intended. How to update only new rows? I've tried putting arguments on the triger but it doesn't accept new.section_id

Comment: Is the `section_id` a unique identifier for a row?  It would be helpful to have the definition of the tables in question, as well.

Comment: @C.Arendt section_id is the primary key for table_a but not for table_b

Comment: What do you mean by arguments on trigger? Like that: `EXECUTE PROCEDURE table_b_aiu(new.section_id);`?
You have access to that row without passing it as argument. You can simply do `where a.section_id = new.section_id` and remove `from table_b` as it is not needed.

Comment: @ŁukaszKamiński after removing the from and trying just new.section_id I got   Provider errors:
      PostGIS error while changing attributes: ERROR:  record "new" has no field "sectionid"

Comment: shouldn't that be `section_id` instead of `sectionid`?

Comment: @ŁukaszKamiński oh yea, it worked, thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So a couple of things.  For this type of question, it is definitely helpful to have access to the table definitions for testing.  I have mocked up what I expect to be the table designs.  Also, it is helpful to include the "desired behavior" (i.e. are you intending to always set the status to be 100?  Regardless of what happens to table_b?).  Also, the `update` statement necessarily hits the entire `table_a`, which is why you need the unique constraint to get a unique record.  If you are mistakenly setting the status to be 100 when it should be `SET status = new.status`, that would be a different issue (but might look like the update is "hitting the whole table", see example below - particularly `section_id=3`).

Hopefully the below illustrates accurate behavior.  I am suspicious that your trigger should be setting `status=new.status`:

```
CREATE TABLE table_a
(
 section_id serial
 , status integer
 , CONSTRAINT pk_table_a PRIMARY KEY (section_id)
);

CREATE TABLE table_b
(
 id serial
 , section_id integer
 , status integer
 , CONSTRAINT pk_table_b_aiu PRIMARY KEY (id)
 )
 ;


CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION table_b_aiu()
RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
UPDATE table_a a
SET status = 100 -- intentional??
WHERE (new.status = 100 or new.status = 200) 
AND a.section_id = new.section_id;

    RETURN new; 
END;
$BODY$
 LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
 COST 100;

CREATE TRIGGER table_b_aiu
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE
ON table_b
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (((new.status = 100) OR (new.status = 200)))
EXECUTE PROCEDURE table_b_aiu();


INSERT INTO table_a (section_id, status)
values (1,100)
, (2,200)
, (3,201)
, (4, 202)
returning *;

| section_id | status |
| 1 | 100 |
| 2 | 200 |
| 3 | 201 |
| 4 | 202 |

INSERT INTO table_b (section_id, status)
values (1,101), (2,100), (3,200), (4,201)
returning *;

| id | section_id | status | 
| 1 | 1 | 101 | 
| 2 | 2 | 100 | 
| 3 | 3 | 200 |
| 4 | 4 | 201 |

select *
from table_a;

| section_id | status |
| 1 | 100 |
| 4 | 202 |
| 2 | 100 |
| 3 | 100 |
```

NOTE: the `new.status in (100,200)` is redundant, but I presume you wanted to be safe (in case someone ever were to set up a trigger without the `when` statement.

My suggestions: if you want to limit the status options on the table itself to 100 / 200, I would suggest creating a foreign key to a `status` table that only has those options.

Comment: Okay so the intended behavior is to just leave status 100 on table_a no matter what. The only single occasion why I would want to change the status back from 100 to something else would be if the line on table_b is invalid and gets deleted but I guess it's another trigger for that

Comment: You could definitely put that logic in the same trigger.  In general, I think that would be preferable, although if it is possibly to relationally design in a way that avoids triggers, that is probably preferable still.  Does the above work in the fashion that you expect?  (If you need to test, you can `SET search_path=otherschema;` to avoid whatever schema you already have tables defined in).

Comment: One other thought - you are having users insert into the log table and updating the parent.  It is possible to let users insert into or update the parent table and create the log table with a trigger (this is the approach I usually follow).  See second to last example [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-createtrigger.html)

Comment: Yea the a.section_id = new.section_id line did the trick. How could I put the delete logic in the same trigger?

Comment: Many ways to do that!  Probably best formulated in a new question with description of logic.  In general, the [postgres docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html) are very good ([also here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/plpgsql-trigger.html)).  Probably some variation of `if/else` logic with an update statement inside.  You can use `IF TG_OP = 'DELETE'` to tell if your trigger executed `ON DELETE` (but of course, you would need to execute the trigger on delete, as well).

Answer (score 1):

Try this function (not tested though)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION table_b_aiu()
RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
    UPDATE table_a
    SET status = 100
    WHERE section_id = NEW.section_id
    RETURN new;
END;
$BODY$
```

Until `section_id` is a primary key on `table_a` it should be enough.